# Header Links showing twice under the Account Links in Mobile Menu Magento 2

Tags: magento2, theme, header, mobile-menu, porto-theme

I am getting Header Links **twice** under the Account Links in **Mobile Menu**. I have attched screenshot of that. You can see in the image there is twice header links under account tab. I'm using porto theme with Magento 2.3.2.

[image]

Any help?

Thanks in advance...!!!

Comment: Have you find any answer?

Comment: I have same issue if you have solution please share with me it's urgent

Comment: @Magento : If you are using Porto as a theme then you can refer Bharat Sevra's answer. that's worked in my case.

Comment: Yes i am using porto theme but as per Bharat Sevra's answer it also hide link in desktop view in dropdown

Comment: @Magento : then try this: @media(max-width: 767px) {
    ul.header.links:first-child {
        display:none;
    }
}

Might be it works for you.

Comment: Yes , it works thnx @BalwantSingh

Comment: @Magento: Welcome :) Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please comment `<move element="top.links" destination="customer"/>` in **../app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Customer/layout/default.xml**

http://prntscr.com/r0nvs2

Comment: It also hide navigation link like my account, Wishlist in desktop view @BharatSevra

Answer (score 2):

I just solved this issue by way of media query. Im not entirely sure what is causing the double injection of the account links, but it seems to me that it is copying the desktop version of those menu items and also adding them to the mobile menu. In order to hide those, I went ahead and added this bit of css

```
@media(max-width: 767px) {
    ul.header.links:first-child {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

this will hide the first list (with the extra fields in there) and only give you "my account" and "sign out". In my case this is all I need, but results may vary.

Comment: This is CSS will hide the default header-links when customer not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

you can start from checking where it comes from:

`grep 'class="header links"' ./app/ ./vendor/ -r`

`grep '<!-- Account Links' ./app/ ./vendor/ -r`

`grep 'MENU BLOCK NAME ID' ./app/ ./vendor/ -r`

and use other search variations.

there are few options:

1. extra line in layout
2. layout reference for links in block mixed
3. other extension injects own menu
4. multiple themes installed and static files deployed from them

when you install magento , go to github and create repository, push your files.
every change you push to github, then you can see it in history.

Answer (score 0):

Please comment  in ../app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Customer/layout/default.xml

https://prnt.sc/w7ngs3